# Batch file to look for pdfs/doc/docx/etc

Tags: list, batch-file, search

Looking for some help with a script to search all folders under c:\users\ for .pdf, .doc, .docx, etc. I am cleaning up some computers with files on them but I don't want to delete user folders just their contents for the most part. This is for a physician office where the users shouldn't be saving anything to the hard drive and I have implemented a no save policy but want to get the existing data off and saved in case they need it for future reference.

Will be running using psexec from a server on 50+ computers. If possible I was hoping the output would be \servername\destinationfolder\computername\username\file.pdf or something similar so I know which computer and user the documents came from.

I thought it'd look something like this using robocopy, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 @echo off
 for /f %%d in ('c:\users') do (
 robocopy c:\users\%%d \\servername\destinationfolder *.pdf /s

 for /f %%e in ('c:\users\%%d') do (
 robocopy c:\users\%%d\%%e \\servername\desinationfolder *.pdf /s
     )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `FOR` command incorrectly, but I think you don't need it at all. The following should cut it as it recurses through every subdirectory beneath `c:\users`, collects the specified files (add extensions as you like) and then copies them to the specified destination.

```
ROBOCOPY c:\users \\servername\destinationfolder *.pdf *.doc *.docx /XJD /S
```

**Edit:** As it turned out, OP is using a newer version of Windows than XP and this fact requires the `/XJD` switch to be added, which...

> ...will prevent Directory Junction Points from being parsed. This avoids
>   a nasty recursion issue that can sometimes occur with Windows' "fake"
>   directories such as "Documents and Settings"

**Edit for completeness:** Motivated by @aschipfl, here's a pointer on what's wrong with the `FOR` command -  [`FOR /F` is used in a quite different way](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). As you wanted to iterate over all the directories of a single level of the filesystem, you could for example do:

```
FOR /D %%D IN ( c:\users\* ) DO ( ... )
```

But, when approaching the task like this, you cannot easily create the directory structure like `ROBOCOPY` does without writing quite a lot of code, and that's just unnecessary when the solution can be as simple as the one above.

Comment: It would be nice if you describe what you mean by "incorrect use" of the `for` command for the OP to learn -- what do you think?

Comment: @aschipfl: You'll laugh, but I actually had typed most of that in, when I realized by using a `FOR` solution, it gets needlessly complicated to replicate `ROBOCOPY`s behaviour of creating subdirectories. So I left it at that. I'm always for passing on knowledge, but in this particular case it didn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @aschipfl: If you really care, I left a note on the matter.

Comment: Thanks @zb226 ! I'm still learning how these commands work. Thanks to this site I get an abundance of information every time! I have tested this and it works great, I did have to make one change to the command. I tried running it just with the robocopy before and it didn't work but here's why..         

`robocopy c:\users \\servername\destinationfolder *.pdf *.doc *.docx /XJD /S`
The /XJD is needed because otherwise it searches the folders that aren't present in Win7 that were in XP (ex. AppData) so it was getting hung up there. After adding /XJD it worked perfectly! Thanks again!!!

Comment: Explanation on the /XJD I found - **/XJD (required) will prevent Directory Junction Points from being parsed. This avoids a nasty recursion issue that can sometimes occur with Windows' "fake" directories such as "Documents and Settings".**

Comment: @MackMan: Excellent! Didn't came across the junction issue as, admittedly, I *was* working on XP yesterday... I'll edit that into the answer... If my answer helped you out, [please do accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)!